# How to draw a line or polygon on Smartface map

Tags: dictionary, smartface.io

Is there any way to draw a polygon on map for different sequence points on Smartface map object?

Answer (score 1):

If you know the points, it is possible to draw polygon with canvas object.
You can find an example at the link below :
http://docs.smartface.io/html/M_SMF_UI_Canvas_drawPolygon.htm

Place the map behind the canvas object. But be aware of that, if you use an object front of map, you won't be able to touch the areas of map that are placed behind the canvas object.

Comment: It is not practical way to do. I think should be added next release!

Comment: Ok, I will think another way. What do you want to show with polygon?

Comment: I think these two documents will help you http://docs.smartface.io/html/M_SMF_UI_MapView_showRoute.htm http://docs.smartface.io/html/E_Device_onLocationChanged.htm

Comment: showroute display the route between two points but i have point array to draw line between them

Comment: Then you should use canvas as I said before. For now there is no option to draw something else on map except route.